# Is there a way to specify Character Spacing in SSRS/BIDS?

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, bids

I am trying to create a SSRS report. The report is essentially as certificate which will be printed on Custom Stationary (Some arty paper like certificates).

The system we are migrating from used Word mail merge to specify the Certificate holder's name, certification date etc. Now we are creating an SSRS report which would essentially generate the Certificate. The font used in the legacy system was Lucida Calligraphy with a Character spacing of 66%. (Attached comparison image) [image]

I could not locate a setting in BIDS to specify character spacing for fonts. Without the spacing things look a little weird and I'd rather not go and tell the client to change their stationary and/or printer because it'll be a logistics havoc.

So the question is, is it possible to specify character spacing in SSRS/BIDS? If yes how? If no what are the alternatives?

Comment: No, there is no such option. Check if you can achieve your goal by exprerimenting with FontSize and FontWeight

Comment: Thanks niktrs. I was afraid of that.

Comment: As niktrs says, can't be done. Another potential workaround is to create graphics and link to those. Not a good workaround, but worth a mention.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have correct character spacing by adding a space between each character and makeing that space to have a size of 8pt (because my text has a size of 16).

It looks good in my report.